# Time Complexity in asymptotic analysis log n and log (n+m)

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

Just some interesting discussion inspired by a conversation in my class.

There are two algorithms, one has time complexity **log n**  and another **log (n+m)**.

Am I correct to argue for average cases, **log (n+m)** one will perform faster while they make no differences in running time when considering it asymptotically? Because taking the limit of both and **f1'/f2'** will result in a constant, therefore they have the same order of growth.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question lacks a lot of context. What is n and what is m? Are those two variables related, or are they completely independent numbers? Are you talking about taking *exactly* log(n) and log(n+m) operations, or are you talking about O(log(n)) and O(log(n+m))?

Comment: For instance, in the case of a graph with n vertices and m edges, we have the relation `m <= n**2`; thus `log(n+m) <= log(n+n**2) < log(2 n**2) = log(2) + 2 log(n) = O(log n)`, so `log(n+m) = O(log n)`.

Comment: Thanks Stef, m and n are the height of the heap and are unrelated. We would like to discuss further on O(log(n)) and O(log(n+m)) case.

Comment: In that case, if there is no assumption on a relation between n and m, then in general O(log(n)) ⊂ O(log(n+m)), which means the statement "the algorithm runs in O(log(n+m))" is a stronger statement (ie, a better speed guarantee) that the statement "the algorithm runs in O(log(n+m))". However, be careful: since the letter m does not appear in O(log(n)), the statement "the algorithm runs in O(log(n))" is a bit ambiguous and it's not clear whether it means that m has no effect on the asymptotical complexity, or whether the effect of m is unstated.

Comment: Thanks! so it is better to say O(log(n)) is bounded by O(log(n+m)), but the asymptotical complexity depends on the actual size of m and n?

Comment: `n` and `m` are *different* variables, what if, say `m = exp(n)`? you'll have `O(log(n))` vs. `O(n)` in this case and `O(n + m) > O(n)`. All you can say in *general* case is `O(n) <= O(m + n)`. If `m` grows *not faster* then *polynom* `P(n)` then `O(n) = O(n + m)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from the question, both `n` and `m` are *independent* variables. So
when stating that

```
O(m + n) = O(n)
```

it should hold for *any* `m`, which is not: the *counter example* is

```
m = exp(n)

O(log(m + n)) = O(log(n + exp(n))) = O(log(exp(n))) = O(n) > O(log(n))
```

That's why in *general case* we can only say, that

```
O(log(m + n)) >= O(log(n))
```

An interesting problem is *when* `O(m + n) = O(n)`. If `m` grows *not faster* then *polynom* from `n`, i.e. `O(m) <= O(P(n))`:

```
O(log(m + n)) = O(log(P(n) + n)) = O(log(P(n))) = k * O(log(n)) = O(log(n))
```

In case of *(multi)graphs* seldom have we that many edges `O(m) > P(n)`:  even complete graph `Kn` contains only `m = n * (n - 1) / 2 = P(n)` edges, that's why

```
O(m + n) = O(n)
```

holds for *ordinary graph* (no parallel/multiple edges, no loops)